In John 8, why did the Jews call themselves "children of Abraham" not "children of Jacob" or something else?
Considering that in the Jewish mindset at the time of Jesus, as we learn from Paul in Romans 9:6-13, the Jews thought that they were "the children of promise" descended from Isaac (not Ishmael) and "God's elect" descended from Jacob (thus Paul citing God's election of Jacob over Esau), why then, in John 8, the Judeans refer to themselves as "children of Abraham" rather than the "children of Jacob" or something else?
I understand that Paul used Abraham as a model of faith, but faith was not the topic in John 8:30-59.  Why did Jesus's interlocutors refer to themselves as "children of Abraham"?  Did they implicitly acknowledge that the Idumeans (roughly the leftover of the Edomites in the Hellenistic period, descendants of Esau) and the inhabitants of the Nabataean Kingdom (descendants of Ishmael according to Josephus) were their brothers too, two neighboring peoples in the South that they looked down on?  Wouldn't it be more natural that in the discussion of freedom they wanted to emphasize to Jesus of their being the children of promise and of their election over Esau? Or to take it one step further, since they were from the Jerusalem area, maybe they should have called themselves "children of Judah" whose ancestors may have stayed there, not ever been "enslaved" (being exiled to Assyria / Babylon)?

The Jewish people certainly knew they were descended from Jacob, using that phrase elsewhere in the scriptures. When they called themselves "children of Abraham" (John 8:33 & 39) when accusing Jesus of being illegitimate (v. 41) and a despised Samaritan (v. 48), they were doing as much mud-slinging at Jesus as they possibly could. This was in order to stop the people putting their trust in him as one who claimed God as his Father and authority (vs. 28-30).
They knew Malachi wrote of God loving Jacob (1:2) and that they were descended from Jacob (Jeremiah 46:27). Further, they knew the scripture where God's covenant was stated to be with Abraham, Isaac and Jacob (2 Kings 13:23). So, when they homed in on Abraham, specifically, in John chapter 8, they were not denying that they were children of Jacob. But they spoke of Abraham in order to insult Jesus as much as they possibly could.
Those Jewish critics would know of Jesus and the disciples going through Samaria, speaking with a woman and all the people in a village near Schechem, which had a well build by Jacob. But the Jews despised the Samaritans. Read 2 Kings 17 for the reason. They were a mixed race, partly descended from the Ten Tribes, partly from Assyrian immigrants. Their faith and practice was founded on the Pentateuch alone. They rejected all of the other Hebrew scriptures. (See Young's Concordance, p. 833, middle column.) So, to call Jesus "a Samaritan" and the offspring of fornication was linked, in their thinking, to utterly cutting him off from any claim to be a descendant of Abraham, never mind Jacob.
The topic in John chapter 8 was Jesus claiming God as his Father and supreme authority. His protagonists were incensed at him, claiming Abraham as their supreme authority, but Jesus turned their claims to naught by saying, "Before Abraham was I am" (v. 58). They couldn't top that.

BTW, your answer also explained v. 33 "we have never been enslaved to anyone", i.e. that they have the Samaritans in mind, who were enslaved to the Assyrians.  Sometimes Bible readers missed that the "Jews" in John's gospel refer to the "Judeans".  Probably that's why they dismissed Jesus's Nazareth hometown for the same reason (John 7:40-42), making the gospel writers emphasized how Jesus was born in Bethlehem and that his father's hometown was the City of David.

The Jews didn't need Jeremiah or Kings to know that they were descended from Jacob.  Their nation was named after him after all ("Israel" being another of Jacob's names).

Covenantal Sonship
In biblical terms, the covenant made with Abraham passes through his only son Isaac, as stated in Genesis 17:19-21; 22:2; Quran 29:27. Isaac is considered the child of promise, while Ishmael, his half-brother through concubine, is not included in this covenantal lineage.

Father of Many Nations: Abraham is regarded as the patriarch of the Jewish people and is seen as the first to enter into a covenant with God. This covenant, which includes the promise of land and numerous descendants, establishes him as a foundational figure in Judaism. The name "Abraham" itself means "father of many," emphasizing his role in the lineage of multiple nations, including the Israelites through Isaac and Jacob (Israel).

Covenant with God: The covenant made with Abraham is a central theme in Jewish theology. It is through Abraham that God promises to create a great nation (the Israelites) and bless all nations through his descendants (Genesis 12:1-3). This covenantal relationship establishes a unique identity for the Jewish people, rooted in their connection to Abraham.


You are presupposing the genealogy of the flesh, if you think children of Abraham (in the Jewish or Biblical sense) would include any other group than the covenantal children through Isaac and Jacob. The references to the sonship through "Abraham" includes Isaac and Jacob. In other words, the discussion in the Gospels about being sons of Abraham is not about genetic lineage, but about covenantal lineage, as their approval for covenantal status makes them heirs of Abraham.

You started well there, but left the thought unfinished.  "You are presupposing the genealogy of the flesh ... In other words, the discussion in the Gospel about being sons of Abraham is not about genetic lineage", but about .... ?   Why use "children of Abraham" in the debate with Jesus?

It is about covenantal lineage rather than genetic lineage. They were not concerned about genetic lineage since they knew Abraham was father of various nations besides them.

I'll rephrase my answer.

OP: why did the Jews refer to themselves as "children of Abraham" rather than "children of Jacob"?


O ye seed of Abraham his servant, ye children of Jacob his chosen. Psalm 105:6

They are of the seed of Abraham via Jacob His chosen.
Jacob, renamed Israel, of course had 12 children, the 12 tribes.
Here's the context to the question.

Then said they unto him, Where is thy Father? Jesus answered, Ye neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also. John 8:19

Basically, they thought Jesus was born from an unknown father.  Maybe Samaria, maybe something else.  They knew He lived with Mary and Joseph who had children after the flesh after Jesus was born, but they accused Him of being a you know what.  Moreover, His family didn't believe in Him, until after resurrection.

I [Jesus] know that ye are Abraham's seed; but ye seek to kill me, because my word hath no place in you. v37

Here Jesus is agreeing with them, setting the stage.  His detractors are Abraham's seed.  They agree.

They answered and said unto him, Abraham is our father. Jesus saith unto them, If ye were Abraham's children, ye would do the works of Abraham. v39

Now they unload and state the obvious.

Ye do the deeds of your father. Then said they to him, We be not born of fornication; we have one Father, even God. v41

Fornication is illicit sexual intercourse.  That's the contrast.  Jesus born from who knows how/what, while they are of Abraham's seed.
The argument escalates until Jesus clamps down.

Jesus said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, Before Abraham was, I am. v58

And of course they then turn to violence and attempt to stone Him.  He leaves.
So, to answer the OP, why did they use the phrase children of Abraham and not children of Jacob is to emphasize their physical lineage versus Jesus' alleged illicit physical lineage source.  It was their claim to the promises versus who is this son of someone.
Hope that clarifies.

I like Anne's answer because there is a recovery of meaning obvious to the original audience that we may miss because of our different cultural and historical milieu.  So this question can be significant in that sense, not that it must be important.  It may be, or it may not.  But it's not "speculation" if we can establish from NT background research that it's an issue that's important to them, important enough that the writer used that word choice.  Only after that proper exegesis we can determine the relevancy for our own milieu.

It's because Isaac is seen as the rightful heir of Abraham, of the promise and convenant made with Abraham, and Jacob as the rightful heir of Isaac, of the same.

Yes, but it's still not clear why they responded to Jesus with Abraham than Jacob, because the covenant promise were inherited by Jacob, so even though the covenant was made to Abraham, they did not have to say "Abraham" to invoke that promise.

As I understand it, the nation of Israel was instigated with God's promise to Abraham, and that promise passed down through Jacob, and so the Father of the nation is Abraham.
